# Why are the who's online avatars on this website bumping eachother down on hover?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, buddypress

`http://minegrumps.com` I'm guessing it's some css somewhere, but man I hate finding that stuff in wordpress, and I've already looked for hours using firebug. A little help would be appreciated.

Solved: The Wordpress theme Evolve uses #secondary for the stuff in widgets, and for some reason that id has the following css:

```
#secondary a:hover, #secondary-2 a:hover { padding-left:5px; }
```

So while the theme claims to be compatible with the buddypress plugin, it doesn't display the currently online widget very well.

Comment: Its called css transitions

Answer (score 0):

The Wordpress theme Evolve uses #secondary for the stuff in widgets, and for some reason that id has the following css:

```
#secondary a:hover, #secondary-2 a:hover { padding-left:5px; }
```

So while the theme claims to be compatible with the buddypress plugin, it doesn't display the currently online widget very well.